# using UIDocumentBrowserViewController only on iOS 11

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios11

I'd like to use the new `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` only in iOS 11, using my old browser for iOS 10 or earlier.

How can I programmatically select the root view controller depending on OS version?

I'm aware of availability macros. I'm interested in the right approach to programmatically presenting the view controller. I'm thinking of doing an initial view controller which immediately triggers a segue to either `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` or my old code depending on the version. But perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: What language? Swift or Objective-C? Update your question with some relevant code showing what you have so far.

Comment: "I'm thinking of doing an initial view controller which immediately triggers a segue to either UIDocumentBrowserViewController or my old code depending on the version." Well that's not going to work, because UIDocumentBrowserViewController must _be_ the initial view controller (the app's root view controller).

Answer (score 0):

You can use availability checking:

## ObjC

Xcode >= 9

```objc
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    // call iOS >= 11.0 API
} else {
    // fallback code
}
```

Xcode < 9

```objc
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"11.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
    // call iOS >= 11.0 API
} else {
    // fallback code
}
```

---

## Swift

```swift
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    // call iOS >= 11.0 API
} else {
    // fallback code
}
```

Comment: Nvm. ObjC - Sol #2..Updated